# Executing a state method from the stateless component

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have a page component let's say `HomePage`. And I have two stateless components called `List` and `ListRow`. The idea is to show the Table with the list of items and when the user clicks on any particular row, hide the table and show the details of that particular row.

So in my `HomePage` render method:

```
<List data={listOfData} onClick={this.clickHanlder} />
```

The `HomePage` click handler method:

```
clickHandler(name) {
  console.log(name);
}
```

And in my `List` stateless component I do this:

```
const List = ({data, onClick}) => {
  return (
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <td>Name</td>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {data.map(el => 
          <ListRow key={el.id} item={el} onClick={onClick} />
        )}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  );
}
```

And in my `ListRow` stateless component I do this:

```
const ListRow = ({item, onClick}) => {
  return (
    <tr>
      <td><a href="#" onClick={onClick(el.name)}>{el.name}</a></td>
    </tr>
  );
}
```

The click handler method in the `HomePage` executes once the page loads without even clicking on the row. When I click on the row, nothing happens.

I'm stuck at how and where to handle the click event, so that I hide the table and show the details of the row. I also should implement close / back button to show the table and hide the details.

What I have done so far is implementing the click event method in `HomePage` which will update its state and pass that method down till the `ListRow` stateless component. But when I load the app itself, the click event gets executed. I'm not sure how to handle this properly.

Comment: Where is the click event?

Comment: @IlanHasanov: That is where I'm confused where to implement. I tried implementing the click event method in the `HomePage` and passing the props to `List` and then `List` passes that to `ListRow`. But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution finally. I was doing it wrong. I've changed the `clickHandler` to as follows:

```
clickHandler(event) {
  console.log(event.target.innerHTML);
}
```

and in my `ListRow` stateless component, I'm doing this:

```
const ListRow = ({item, onClick}) => {
  return (
    <tr>
      <td><a href="#" onClick={onClick}>{el.name}</a></td>
    </tr>
  );
}
```

The mistake I was doing is that I was trying to pass the value to the onClick event which seems doesn't work. So using the innerHTML resolved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It's idiomatic in React to implement container components that will handle (for example) click events, population etc. So in your case you can create a handler for the row/item click in the *List* component and pass a reference to that down to the *ListRow* component as one of its *props*.

Even though it's stateless, your *List* component can still declare a function to handle the click; look at the example shown at the top of this article:

https://medium.com/@housecor/react-stateless-functional-components-nine-wins-you-might-have-overlooked-997b0d933dbc#.9sxosb40u

However you can't use any of the React lifecycle methods or state. If you want to use these you would need to wrap it as shown here:

https://egghead.io/lessons/javascript-redux-fetching-data-on-route-change

Comment: How do I update the state of the `HomePage` if I implement the click in the `List` component?

Comment: You can declare the click handler in you HomePage component, which mean cascading it down via props to List and then on to ListRow. If this seems unwieldly consider using redux to manage global application state.

Comment: Updated the question with how I'm using the click handler. I'm doing exactly as you are suggesting, but that is not working.